# How to develop app for galaxy s and tab in android

Tags: android, drawable

I developed an app for samsung galaxy s and samsung tab. I placed the images in res/drawable-mdpi for galaxy s and for galaxy tab i place it in res/drawable-hdpi is it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. In fact, you can place all of your images to the drawable-hdpi folder and they will be scaled automatically for the Galaxy S

Comment: @ Anton if i want to use it on same hdpi then i need to give different naming conventions right......

Comment: @user1051599 If your images are the same, then you will only need one copy of your drawables in one folder and framework will do the rest for you. But if the images are significantly different, then you need to stick to the mdpi/hdpi folder

Comment: @ Anton basically height and width size for any image but it should support both gal s and gal tab how can i give.......